# Passing data between two plain js files in ejs templating

Tags: javascript, node.js, export, ejs

my file structure is as follows:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5XZN.png)

I have two ejs views. I am taking a variable from index.ejs using document.querySelector. This variable is stored in index.js file.
I need to access this variable in board.js
How can I do so?

I have tried using:
`module.exorts = varName` and then `require` in board.js but it isn't working

index.js file

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".level1");
var levelMode;
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  levelMode = btn.innerHTML;
  alert(levelMode);
});

module.exports = levelMode;
```

board.js file

```
var levelMode = require("./index")
```

The console shows the following error:

```
uncaught reference: require is not defined
```

Comment: You could just save it to document, window, local storage or a cookie to reuse it throughout the entire application. Another solution would be to send it to the server and fetch the information from other files.

Answer (score 0):

Im a new developer so take my advice with a grain of salt, but I feel I need to start by saying that js files dont "store" information that isn't the source code. Any information that you feel you need to pull from a variable is stored by the browser running the js file. If you need to pull data from the client my best advice is to first pass it to the server. You should get more familiar with the module you are using for HTTP Requests.